# How to config solr to make sure word position

Tags: solr

```
I use solr 6.0 edismax search with WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.
I want to get the result the same with search word position.
```

*for example,search: AA BB CC*

*response:  (AA XXX BB XXX CC) / (XXX AA XXX BB CC XXX).*

*Not included:  CC XXX AA XXX BB,XXX AA CC XXX BB,CC BB AA and so on.*

Answer (score 1):

This is [supported by the ComplexPhraseQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser), by giving it `inOrder=true` and having a large (more than your largest count of tokens) distance between the tokens:

```
{!complexphrase inOrder=true}content:"foo bar"~1000
```

.. find everything where "foo" appears before "bar". While

```
{!complexphrase inOrder=true}content:"bar foo"~1000
```

does not given any results (which it does with a regular phrase query). So for your use case:

```
{!complexphrase inOrder=true}content:"AA BB CC"~10000
```